# curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Tags: ruby, curl, terminal, homebrew

I know some people have asked this question before but I don't understand some of the answers. I'm a Mac user trying to instal **Homebrew** but I keep getting this error message:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host)
```

whenever I enter this code in the terminal:

```
ruby <(curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

Can anyone explain to me how to resolve this and bear in mind I am a newbie to code.

Comment: what happens if you use http:// instead of https?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a ruby/curl problem but simply a problem with your network.

What the line does is fetching `curl -fsSk https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go` and executing it as ruby code. The error you get is from curl which was not able to connect to the host.

So you need to figure out why curl cannot fetch that URL. Use a plain `curl https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go` to see if you get any useful errors, but most likely not since it *simply couldn't connect*.

Comment: I keep getting the same error. Could it be because I'm trying this at work? I have proxy access because of my line of work but there are some sites I am unable to access.

Comment: That might indeed be the case.